# Best place to get Salary Information

Tags: salary

I am trying to figure out whether my salary is what it should be and was curious where people go to find salary information? I have looked at Indeed and Salary.com. Both looked like the salaries were higher than I expected, so I wasn't sure if those were the best sites.

I am a software engineer living in Boston with about ~9 years of experience making low 90's. I would consider myself an above average developer. When typing this information into Salary.com it says that average person with 8-10 years makes 130K. Hence, I am trying to figure out how to get accurate information.

Comment: Glassdoor FTW!!

Answer (score 4):

I have had a lot of success with [Glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com) and found the salaries to be directionally correct. Just be careful when researching companies that employ throughout the US as salaries will vary depending on cost of living.

Comment: Yes, when looking at GlassDoor salaries, there is a dropdown at the top that allows you to filter the results by city specifically for the reason of differing average salaries based on location.